# Numbers not adding to LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

I want do add numbers to a pre-existing amount in LocalStorage. What I find after is that it is indeed recognised that there is a new amount, but when I refresh the page it doesn't keep to LocalStorage...

```js
//Just making an index
localStorage.setItem("currentUser",10)

//This makes currentUser.whatever into something viable
var currentUser = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usersArray')))[localStorage.getItem("currentUser")];

//I add the number to the pre-existing amount
currentUser.goldAmount = currentUser.goldAmount + 50;

//For reference 100 is a pre-existing amount for goldAmount, so it should now be 120. It does alert that although when i refresh the page and do it again its not 200, but still 150. It resets back to 100 every restart...
  alert(currentUser.goldAmount);
```

Appreciate the Help :)

Comment: Where's the code where you save the new amount back to localstorage?

Comment: after changing the value again you have to set it in localstorage or it wont update.

Comment: You need to store the updated value back into the localStorage, also, you should keep in mind that everything is stored as a "string"in local store, you may need to parseInt the values for correct mathematical operations.

Comment: After the add operation, you will need to save that value back to the localStorage. Making any operation on variable won't automatically effect the localStorage. By fetching the item from localStorage, you are only copying the value of it, AND not creating an instance of it

Comment: Say that goldAmount was part of an array of objects... Would I need to rewrite the whole array, modify the object of currentUser.goldAmount and then set it to localStorage?

Comment: @Macint0sh_Plus Yeah, you just resave the "usersArray"

Answer (score -1):

Try checking whats inside your JSON and the currentUser object.
Note that if the JSON contains
`{"currentUser":{"goldAmount":10}}`
Than you will need to read it like
`currentUser.currentUser.goldAmount`
`variable`     `in-json var` `requested var`